# My 2014 Hyundai Veloster's clock only progresses when my car is on after being stolen?

Tags: hyundai, dashboard

My car was stolen last month. It's been recovered and a dealership repaired the driver lock and ignition back to working order. Except the clock. Ever since I got the car back, the clock only progresses when the car's electronics are on. It remembers what the previous time was when I turned the vehicle off, but if I wait minutes or hours the clock won't think a second has passed.

Apparently Hyundais and Kias produced around the time my car was produced (2014) are easy to steal because the key doesn't have to be present in the ignition once the car is on. So I'm told.

The way they broke into my car didn't involve yanking wires or hot wiring anything. So I'm not sure what the root problem is. How can I fix the clock in my car?

Comment: It sounds like the clock is now powered via a switched power source and not a constant on source. Does the radio reset every time you turn the car off/on? If so, they might have done something wrong when putting in a new ignition cylinder.

Comment: No, nothing resets. My saved bluetooth connections and radio stations are all there. The radio stays where it was last tuned. If the clock said 3:03 AM when I turned it off, it says 3:03 AM when I turn it back on.

Comment: No clue then. That truly is a strange thing. The only other thing I might suggest is to disconnect the battery and let the vehicle sit for at least 30 minutes (this will drain any residual energy), then plug the battery back in and see if the clock is reset. Thinking a full reset might get it to run correctly.

Comment: I had my doubts, but it worked. 11AM this morning I disconnect the negative terminal, Noon I reconnect it and set the clock to the proper time, now it's 1:20PM and when I started my car the time was correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, you might try to disconnect the battery and reconnect it 30 minutes later. This will allow all residual energy to be used up in the vehicle. Doing this might reset the clock and allow it to function correctly again.

Comment: It's such a small annoyance that ultimately doesn't make a difference, but I'm so glad this worked. My sanity thanks you.